# Bottom margins for smaller headers are too big (in the editing preview and on the site)

Tags: feature-request, design

Smaller headers (HTML tags H2 and H3) should be closer to the text they are meant to be a header of.

## Test header H1

This text is close to H1.

### Test header h2 which is closer to previous text than to text it's a header of

Text that is too far from the header h2.

#### Test header h3

This text is too far as well.

**Update**

After posting this I discovered that the issue is amplified in the preview.
Margins are not *that* bad after editing (but still could be smaller), but it were the margins *in the preview* that urged me to post this.

**Update 2**
Checked the Android app. The issue is present there as well.